# Is Kinect required for Zoo Tycoon?

Tags: xbox-one, zoo-tycoon-2013

I'm interested in buying the Xbox One version of Zoo Tycoon sometime in the next few months, but I don't have/won't foreseeably be getting a Kinect. I can't find any information on if the Xbox One version *requires* it, so does anyone here know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not required. My Kinect doesn't work, but this game still does.

Answer (score 2):

According to [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/xbox-one/List_of_Xbox_One_Kinect_Games) these are the things you can do with Kinect:

> **Zoo Tycoon**    The Kinect gives you the ability to feed, dance, or play with your animals that you currently have in your zoo which you gives you the chance to bond with your animals.

Together with the previous answer I can conclude it is indeed not necessary, just a nice (if you're into things like that) gimmick

Comment: Some (of not all) of these 'interactions' (as the game calls them) can be done with the pad.

Answer (score 0):

While not strictly required, having the kinect greatly improves Zoo Tycoon, because of the voice commands. With the kinect hooked up you can just call out overlays you want to see rather than tediously digging through menus.

I played it on the 360 which had the voice action but not the kinect motion action, so there is some assumption on my part that the One version had voice recognition as well done as the 360 version.